# Can I add UIbutton to cover part of UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem to add `UIButton` on `UITableViewController`. I want to add fixed position `UIButton` on top of `UITableViewController`, I have no idea how to do that.

I want something like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui3DY.jpg

`Note` : I have used `UITableViewController` embedded with `UINavigationController`

Comment: you can use UIButton as UITableView footer view.

Comment: Why would you like to do that. That is however possible by extending UITableViewController. But my suggestion is to keep it simple, if you don't need dynamic number of cell don't use UITableViewController or if you need button for UITableView why not put that in the bar?

Comment: Based on your screenshot, shouldn't you be using `UICollectionView` and not `UITableView` in the first place?

Comment: Jeet, actually it has so many contents on UITableViewCell. That why I choose UITableViewController.

Comment: You can use a UIViewController with a UIButton and a UITableView.Set the positions using auto layout in storyboard.Set the data source and delegate of the tableview to be the view controller class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put other subviews in a UITableViewController.

Instead what do you want to do is embed a UITableViewController as a child view of another view controller. Look up embed segues.